# Serialize/deserialize protobuf message with TMQ (rust)

Tags: serialization, rust, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I am trying to use protobuf (https://github.com/stepancheg/rust-protobuf) with TMQ (https://github.com/cetra3/tmq) and am having some issues with byte serialization/deserialization for sending over the wire.

I've looked over the documentation, but it's not obvious to me which methods or traits would allow me to convert a protobuf `Message` a type that would be acceptable by `tmq::dealer::Dealer::send()`. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you just mean `tmq::Message::from(your_protobuf_message.write_to_bytes().unwrap())`?